# OpenSwan Automatic Routing Script

Tags: vpn, ipsec

It seems that Openswan does his routing at the running of the ipsec service.
So how is it supposed to work in configmode (where the IP address is given after the routing).

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

openswan doesn't use "ip route"'s routing rules , it uses transformation policies to redirect packets into the encryption tunnels.
you can use "sudo ip xfrm policy show" to view the current deployed transformation policies.

openswan will install these policies automatically upon tunnel establishment and will remove them when the tunnel goes done

Hope this helps

Comment: So when a ping is sent to the remote subnet how does openswan know how to route the packets?